# Blank figure created in python while using seaborn

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

When I am making plots in Python using seaborn I sometimes end up getting a blank plot in between the plots I want.  My data here is a simple dataframe (not shown in code).  When I make figure 3 it shows up correctly, as does figure 4, but figure 5 is blank and what I thought should plot as figure 5 plots in a window called figure 6. I am using Python 3.6 in Spyder IDE.

Why is there a blank figure window showing up?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns    

plt.figure(3)
fig = sns.countplot(data=df, x=df['month'], hue=df['reasons'])
plt.show()

plt.figure(4)
fig = byMonth['twp'].plot()
plt.show()

plt.figure(5)
fig = sns.lmplot(x='new_ind', y='title', data=byMonth)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Note, that if I remove the plt.figure(5) that the blank plot goes away.  But I want to understand why it is creating the blank when I use very similar methods int he code above without that behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `seaborn.lmplot` creates its own figure, and it does so after `plt.figure(5)` is created, the lmplot is shown in the next figure. Since there is nothing assigned to `plt.figure(5)`, this figure will stay empty.

The solution is to remove `plt.figure(5)`, because this extra figure is not needed.

For reference, those plots listed under "Axis Grids" in the seaborn API [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/api.html) will create their own figure:

FacetGrid, 
factorplot,
lmplot,
PairGrid,
pairplot,
JointGrid,
jointplot.